# Composer is not recognizing PHP 7

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

I created a travis profile to test my project from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.

I am getting the following error when composer is run:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~5.4 but your PHP version (7.0.1-dev) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

the command that I am running is:

```
composer update -n
```

with travis set to environment PHP 5.6 I do not run into this issue

Comment: Can you please provide the require-block of your composer.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A package that you use, or your own software itself, explicitly requires a PHP 5.x version (*`~5.4`*), with x being at least 4, or higher (i.e. it would run with PHP 5.5, 5.6, or even 5.10 if it would exist).

This package does not allow PHP 7. That's why you cannot run `composer update` successfully.

Comment: had a php block in the required `"php": "~5.4",`. tks

Answer (score 16):

If the platform requirement is in your root package, you can solve it by amending `composer.json` as such

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.4 | ^7.0"
    } 
}
```

You could also try to ignore platform requirements, but depends on whether you actually want to see that happen:

```
$ composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install.

Comment: I dont like using --ignore-platform-reqs as I'm using travis to do continuous tests.

Comment: How about adjusting your platform requirements as suggested, @azngunit81?

Answer (score 4):

check your composer.json file,
delete this code:

```
 "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.x.1"  // Or change 5.x.1 to your php version
    }
},
```

Comment: Resolved my issue. I was running PHP7, but it kept saying I was on 5.5.9. This was why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `php` default V

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```